# Pandas: get the most count label

Tags: python, pandas

My `dataframe` has a column contains various type values, I want to get the most counted one:

[image]

In this case, I want to get the label `FM-15`, so later on I can query data only labled by this.

How can I do that?

---

Now I can get away with:

```
most_count = df['type'].value_counts().max()
s = df['type'].value_counts()
s[s == most_count].index
```

This returns

```
Index([u'FM-15'], dtype='object')
```

But I feel this is to ugly, and I don't know how to use this `Index()` object to query `df`. I only know something like `df = df[(df['type'] == 'FM-15')]`.

Comment: By default `value_counts()` sorts the result, so just get the 0th index, e.g. `df['type'].value_counts().index[0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `argmax`:

```
lbl = df['type'].value_counts().argmax()
```

To query,

```
df.query("type==@lbl")
```

Comment: `.query` performs better than `df = df[(df['type'] == 'FM-15')]`

Comment: `value_counts()` by default already sorts the results... `.index[0]` should be sufficient.

Comment: @AChampion that's true. But personally, I'm in favor of a more expressive way.

Comment: An addtional question, is it possible to get the 2nd biggest `index`? Or get the whole indexs into an array?

Comment: To get the index of a pandas Series `ser` as a Python list, do `ser.index.tolist()`. As @AChampion commented, `value_counts()` are sorted by default, so `df['type'].value_counts().index[1]` should give you 2nd biggest index. You don't have to convert the index to a list.

Comment: As of pandas 1.1.1, `argmax` returns the [int position of the largest value in the Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argmax.html). Use `idxmax` to get [the row label of the maximum value](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html#pandas.Series.idxmax).